# How to animate model correctly

Tags: c++, animation, mfc

I have an animation which need to be animated. I have some code example

```
void CAnimationEditor::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == 2)
    {
        if (_flAnimPos >= 1.0f)
            _flAnimPos = 0.0f;
        std::chrono::duration<float> elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - _start;
        float time = elapsed_seconds.count();
        float rate = (float)_FPS / m_pAnimation->GetFramesCount();
        _flAnimPos += time * rate;
        if (_flAnimPos >= 1.0f)
            _flAnimPos = 0.0f;
        m_pAnimation->Update();
        m_oglAnimationPreview.Draw();
        _start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

I click on checkbox and set the timer

```
SetTimer(2, 0, NULL);
```

The correct way to animate is "fill" `_flAnimPos` from `0` to `1` in `1.0f / rate` seconds.

For example, I have an animation that consists of 8 frames. If i set `_FPS` to `16`, animation must go through a full cycle in `0.5` seconds.

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The time points were delivered incorrectly. The correct was is:

```
if (nIDEvent == 2)
{
    _start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<float> elapsed_seconds = _start - _last;
    float time = elapsed_seconds.count();
    float rate = (float)_FPS / m_pAnimation->GetFramesCount();
    _flAnimPos += time * rate;
    if (_flAnimPos > 1.0f)
        _flAnimPos = fmod(_flAnimPos, 1.0f);
    m_pAnimation->Update();
    m_oglAnimationPreview.Draw();
    _last = _start;
}
```